# Cannot find symbol variable Android Studio

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-studio, key

I am working on parsing data from a JSON url.
But the JSONobjects have different keys.
I want to get all the data from each json object and when it doesn't have that key I want to give it a default message.

This is what I'm trying to use:

```
if(myJSONObject.has("mykey")) {    <- in this case "abv"
    //it has it, do appropriate processing
}
```

I got this variable

```
private static final String TAG_ABV = "abv";
```

I tried doing this to check if the abv key was included in the JSON and give the string a default text of "No value" when it was not inculed.

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    data = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                    // looping through All 
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {


                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        if(c.has("abv")) {
                            String abv = c.getString(TAG_ABV);
                        } else {
                            String abv = "No value";
                        }

                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        data.put(TAG_ABV, abv);

                        dataList.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

But I have this error: cannot find symbol variable abv
I guess the abv inside the if statement is out the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `abv` inside the if/else blocks, which means it's only accessible inside that block. When you try to use it later (in `data.put(TAG_ABV, abv);` the variable you created is no longer accessible - it's out of scope. If you move the declaration of `abv` to the line before the if/else statement, that should fix your error.

Comment: But I want the if statement to check if the key abv is inside the jsonobject. If the key is inside the JSON object the string abv should get the value of the abv key value otherwise it should get a default text.

Comment: Right, so you want to declare your variable first (`String abv;`) and then assign it a value (`abv = ...`) based on whether the key 'abv' was found inside the JSON object (`if(c.has("abv") { ... } else { ... }`).